# Python version Check (major attribute)

Tags: python, sys, versioninfo

What does `sys.version_info.major` do?

I understand that `sys.version_info` returns the version of interpreter we are using. What role does `major` have to do in this?

How does it work in the following code?

```py
import sys 

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    #code  here   
else:
    #code here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

major can tell you whether it's python2 or python3. I guess it imports different libraries depends on the specific python versions.

I am using python 3.5.1, you can see the `version_info` about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trite example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys 
  if sys.version_info.major<3:
           input = raw_input  # Python2 ~== eval(input())  
  else:
            #code here
```

This makes Python 2.x behave a bit more like Python 3 ... the ***future*** import cannot be in the *if* suite because it must appear before other imports.  But the changes in semantics for the *input()* builtin function between Python 2.x and Python 3 can handled in a conditional.

For the most part it's a bad idea to go much beyond this in your efforts to support Python2 and Python3 in the same file.

The more challenging changes between Python2 and Python3 relate to strings as bytes vs. the newer strings as Unicode; and thus the need to explicitly specify encodings and use *bytes* objects for many networking protocols and APIs.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have Python 3.5.3 installed on my computer. `sys_version` stores the following information:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

The reason version is split into `major`, `minor` and `micro` is that programmers writing code for multiple versions of Python may need to differentiate between them somehow. Most differences are between major versions 2 and 3 of Python and that explains the context of `major` usage in your code.